# Bootstrap 4 form with Ajax, PHP POST and JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, bootstrap-4

I am new to Bootstrap 4 and coding. I have made a contact form and want it to validate on the server side as well as client side. I have used "invalid-feedback" class with a message and added "is-invalid" to the form control. Have also added required to all but the phone number inputs.

I have managed to put together some PHP and Ajax by looking at other examples online. A lot of code seems to be for Bootstrap 3 even though it says it is using Bootstrap 4. So it uses "help-block with-errors" instead of "invalid-feedback".

I have tried to use the POST method in the contact form and also novalidate so I can write my own validation messages. I have also used json encode method in Ajax and PHP. I would really appreciate some help and advice to check my code to see if I am on the right track with getting my success and error messages to work in the PHP and Ajax, to make sure I am also able to collect the form data and get an email sent to me if it all works.

Thank you and be kind.

Please see below my html, PHP, Ajax and css.

I can get the form to show invalid fields and valid fields. But I am not getting the contact success message to work when the form is successfully submitted. Not sure if the PHP and Ajax code are working together?

```js
// JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  "use strict";
  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
      var forms = document.getElementsByClassName("needs-validation");
      // Loop over them and prevent submission
      var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
        form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
            if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
              event.preventDefault();
              event.stopPropagation();
            }
            form.classList.add("was-validated");

            // Here you are going to add your ajax call after checking if the form validation is valid
            if (form.checkValidity() === true) {
              event.preventDefault();
              // To reset the appearance of the form (for instance, in the case of dynamic form submissions using AJAX), remove the .was-validated class from the <form> again after submission. (bootstrap doc)
              form.classList.remove("was-validated");
              $.ajax({
                url: "contact.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                  console.log(data); // show response from the php script. (use the developer toolbar console, firefox firebug or chrome inspector console)
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                  console.error(xhr);
                }
              });
            }

          },
          false);
      });
    },
    false);
})();
```

```css
#contactform {}

.contactform {
  padding-top: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 300px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.contactbluetext {
  font-variant: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: "Proxima Nova", sans-serif;
  color: #3D4975;
}

.contactbluetext a {
  color: #3D4975;
}

.contactbluetext a:hover,
.contactbluetext a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FF6D2D;
}

.contacth1blueitalictext {
  font-family: "Adobe Garamond Pro Italic", serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-variant: normal;
  color: #3D4975;
}

hr.linecontact {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: block;
  width: 4rem;
}

.contacth3text {
  font-variant: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: "Proxima Nova", sans-serif;
  color: #FF6D2D;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.contacth5orangetext {
  color: #FF6D2D;
  line-height: 1.7rem;
}

.contacth5text {
  line-height: 1.7rem;
}

#contactsuccess {
  display: none;
  color: #FF6D2D;
}

#contactform .contactbutton {
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  padding: .3rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #3D4975;
  -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
}

#contactform .contactbutton:focus,
#contactform .contactbutton:hover {
  background-color: #FF6D2D;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.form-control {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.form-control.is-valid:focus,
.was-validated :valid.form-control {
  border-color: inherit !important;
  background-image: inherit !important;
  box-shadow: inherit !important;
}
```

```html
<section class="contactform contactbluetext" id="contactform">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-7 mb-4">
      <form action="/contact.php" role="form" method="post" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label class="sr-only" for="fname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" id="fname" placeholder="Your first name *" name="fname" aria-describedby="fnamefeedback" required>
            <div id="fnamefeedback" class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your first name</div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label class="sr-only" for="lname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" id="lname" placeholder="Your last name *" name="lname" aria-describedby="lnamefeedback" required>
            <div id="lnamefeedback" class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your last name</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control is-invalid" id="email" placeholder="Your email *" name="email" aria-describedby="emailfeedback" required>
            <div id="emailfeedback" class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your email</div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label class="sr-only" for="phone">Phone</label>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Your phone number" name="phone">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-4">
          <label class="sr-only" for="message">Message</label>
          <textarea class="form-control is-invalid" placeholder="Your Message *" rows="5" id="message" name="message" aria-describedby="messagefeedback" required></textarea>
          <div id="messagefeedback" class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your message</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-check">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="terms">
              <input class="form-check-input is-invalid" type="checkbox" id="terms" name="terms" aria-describedby="termsfeedback" required>
              I agree to the terms of use
              <div id="termsfeedback" class="invalid-feedback">Please tick this box</div>
              </label>
        </div>
        <div id="contactsuccess" class="text-center">Thank you for your message.</div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn contactbutton">Send message</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
</main>


<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-4.6.0.js"></script>
<script>
```

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$fname = $lname = $email = $phone = $message = $terms = "";
$fnameErr = $lnameErr = $emailErr = $phoneErr = $messageErr = $termsErr = "";

if ( isset( $_POST[ "submit" ] ) ) {
$fname = $_POST[ 'fname' ];
$lname = $_POST[ 'lname' ];
$email = $_POST[ 'email' ];
$phone = $_POST[ 'phone' ];
$message = $_POST[ 'message' ];
$terms = $_POST[ 'terms' ];

//valid address on your web server
$from = 'noreply@yourdomain.com ';

//your email address where you wish to receive mail
$to = 'you@yourdomain.com';
$subject = 'Online Form Message';
$headers = "From:$from\r\nReply-to:$email";
$body = "From: $fname\n $lname\n E-Mail: $email\n Phone: $phone\n Message: $message";

// Check if first name is entered

if ( $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_METHOD" ] == "POST" ) {
if ( empty( $_POST[ "fname" ] ) ) {
$fnameErr = "Please enter your first name";
} else {
$fname = test_input( $_POST[ "fname" ] );
}

// Check if last name is entered

if ( empty( $_POST[ "lname" ] ) ) {
$lnameErr = "Please enter your last name";
} else {
$lname = test_input( $_POST[ "lname" ] );
}

// Check if email is entered

if ( empty( $_POST[ "email" ] ) ) {
$emailErr = "Please enter your email";
} else {
$email = test_input( $_POST[ "email" ] );

// check if e-mail address is well-formed
if ( !filter_var( $email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ) {
$emailErr = "Invalid email format";
}
}

// Check if phone is entered although it is not required so we don't need error message

if ( empty( $_POST[ "phone" ] ) ) {
$phone = "";
} else {
$phone = test_input( $_POST[ "phone" ] );
}

//Check if message is entered

if ( empty( $_POST[ "message" ] ) ) {
$messageErr = "Please enter your message";
} else {
$message = test_input( $_POST[ "message" ] );
}

//Check if terms is checked

if ( empty( $_POST[ "terms" ] ) ) {
$termsErr = "Please tick this box";
} else {
$terms = test_input( $_POST[ "terms" ] );
} 
}

// If there are no errors, send the email & output results to the form
if ( !$fnameErr && !$lnameErr && !$emailErr && !$phoneErr && !$messageErr && !$termsErr ) {
if ( mail( $to, $subject, $body, $from ) ) {
$contactsuccess = "Thank you for your message";
}
}
//sanitize data inputs   
function test_input( $data ) {
$data = trim( $data );
$data = stripslashes( $data );
$data = htmlspecialchars( $data );
$data = ( filter_var( $data, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) );
return $data;
}

echo json_encode( $_POST );

}

?>
```

Comment: What specifically is the problem you're having? We're not here to review your entire code just in case. You can ask us if you have an actual issue. To know whether you're on the "right track" you need to be testing and debugging your code - and frankly you should have been doing that before this point anyway, to verify each individual component of the system before plugging it all together.

Comment: P.s. if you're new to coding, then why bootstrap 4? Version 5 is already released. Not much point in learning something which is already out of date.

Comment: I have tested and am having trouble with PHP and ajax results soon submit. I used Bootstrap 4 before 5 came out. Any help would be great!

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about the problem please. Edit your question to give details

Comment: @LPlates If I understand correctly, you're not getting `$contactsuccess` displayed in the front-end part of your webapp? Are you echoing it anywhere? The only thing I see in your code is `echo json_encode($_POST)`. Are you sure you want to `echo` that, and not `$contactsuccess`?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I am not getting $contactsuccess to display front end. I do want it to echo but wasn’t sure how to echo it correctly?

Comment: Any help would be appreciated to echo $contact success please. Thank you.

Comment: `echo $contactsuccess;`??

Comment: I have asked already ADyson for some help with my Php as I am not able to get the success messages to work. So I am still hoping some kind person will advise me what I am doing wrong in my php or JavaScript. Thank you.

Comment: Well I just made a suggestion... You say you want to echo that variable, so why aren't you echoing it?

Comment: Because I don’t know the correct way to echo it which is why I am asking for somebody to kindly help me.

Comment: Well I showed you how to echo it. Not clear what else you want to know? Once you echo it, it will show in the response which is given back to the JavaScript, and should appear in the console. After that, you can write whatever JavaScript you want in order to put it onto the page somewhere

Comment: First you'll need to remove `dataType: "json"` from the Ajax options though, since you'll be sending plain text back, rather than JSON

Comment: Okay thank you. Is there anything else I need to change in my PHP coding or does it look okay?

Comment: I can't see anything obvious, unless you mention another problem after more testing

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.